# Duplicate JavaFX project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2

I want to duplicate a JavaFX project as a sort of "poor man's version control" in Netbeans.

I copied the project into a different folder. Now when I try to create a new project I see no option "Create JavaFX project from existing sources" (an alternative that exists for regular Java projects).

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively right click the project in Netbeans and select "*Copy...*".

Comment: This just seems to move the project, not copy it.

Comment: No for moving there is another menu "Move..." just above "Copy...".

Comment: No it worked; it just created an identical copy so I did  not notice it. Thanks.